# UISearchController does not display anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem with `UISearchController`, it is declared in my "`FindUsersTableViewController.h`" file used to display the searched users.
So, all is in the title, I give you more details with important parts of code of the "`FindUsersTableViewController.m`" file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.searchResults.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *userCellId = @"userCell";

    UserCell *userCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:userCellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // "self.searchedUser" is a property declared as PFUser in the .h file
    PFUser *tempSrchUser = self.searchedUser;
   // "self.searchResults" is a property declared as NSMutableArray in the .h file too, it contains the searched users
    PFObject *searchedUser = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *tempUsername = [searchedUser objectForKey:tempSrchUser.username];

    userCell.usernameLbl.text = tempUsername;

    NSLog(@"retrieved appropriates usernames: %@", userCell.usernameLbl.text);

    return userCell;
}
```

The UISearchController does not display anything... Does anyone knows how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the delegate method [- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchResultsUpdating_ClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchResultsUpdating/updateSearchResultsForSearchController:)

?  This is required and you need to do the filtering here.

Comment: Thx for the answer but I've already fixed the problem by myself with the time :)
My problem now is with the "cancel" button when I come back to the search View Controller, the search bar disappears when I click on. I think I have to ask another question for this :/